# In Android is it possible to disable an Edit Text in a layout when a radio button is selected

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a vertical layout of 4 Edit Text numeric inputs and 4 Radio uttons to determine the required solution of an equation with a button to perform the calculation.

```
Edit Text input a  ,
Edit Text input b  ,
Edit text input c  ,
Edit Text input d  ,

Radio Button solve for a ,
Radio Button solve for b ,
Radio Button solve for c ,
Radio Button solve for d , 

Button Calculate
```

If solve for a is selected then Edit Text a is not required, if solve for b is selected then Edit Text b is not required and the same for c & d.

Can the corresponding Edit Text be disabled on selection of the Radio Button or do I need to provide a separate Layout for each selection. Everything works fine and the result is correct . I can ignore the input that is not required within the main activity but it does not seem to be the correct answer.

I am very much a beginner and I am surprised I have got this far to date. Can anyone please help.Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following way,

```
// radio button chkButton and EditText myEditText

if ( chkButton.isChecked() == true )
{
     myEditText.setEnabled ( false );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lucifer sorry to be slow responding, ChkButton.isChecked() is fine myEditText.setEnabled (false) draws error myEditText cannot be resolved.

Comment: The code is too long to paste in the comments box it will not send.How do you upload the code?. I apologize but I am stuck.

Comment: just paste the if line, i want to see how you wrote if condition.

Comment: Lucifer thanks for your patience                              if (voltsButton.isChecked()==true) 
        {
     
          voltageEditText.setEnabled(false);}

Comment: @ColinScope, condition is perfect, then whats error you are getting ?

Comment: Thanks Lucifer I thought you had given up on me.The error is voltageEditText cannot be resolved.I have checked the layout,xml and the strings.xml files everything is there and the spelling is correct

Comment: oh ok, sorry i was little busy yesterday thereafter, good that your error has been solved, enjoy coding :)